# Mojang/minecraft Password not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to login to the minecraft.net site to check something, using my email address but it said : `Invalid Password/Username.` So i tried the same on the Mojang site but it still said : `Invalid Password/Username.`

I reset the password then, that was successful, but when i tried to login with my new password, it still said the same. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Have you migrated you account? That's the problem in most cases. If so, please login like this:

```
Username: <put your email here e.g. hello@world.com>
Password: ************
```